# How to decrease LibreOffice icons size?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-netbook, icons, libreoffice

I'm using a netbook which runs Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal Beta. This new interface is really exciting and it's creating very effective experiment on daily use. As you know, there are still some problems and bugs out there. In LibreOffice, I couldn't decrease the size of icons and this matter makes me a bit angry. Please help on this topic, I'll be waiting for answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Likely relevant: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101646

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I like how you found about this question after all those years, and I'm also amazed that there is still ongoing discussion and bug report regarding to this. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm glad the link I provided was useful to you.  Yes, it's amazing that 11 years later, this is still an issue.  Kinda reminds me of Firefox, where there are some reported issues that still haven't been resolved for about 20 years!  I think Firefox is amazing, but how any issue can be left unresolved for 20 years is, well, um, hrmm, ummm... less than ideal! ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have the options for icon size changed after it forked from OpenOffice? In Openoffice on my Maverick netbook I can reduce the size under *Tools > Options > OpenOffice.org [probably LibreOffice now] > View*. It sounds strange that they would remove the feature from LibreOffice.

If it's missing, you should probably [file a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi) with LibreOffice.